# How to return a value if an error-free R function does not do so

Tags: r, function, null, return-value

My goal is to assign a plot produced by the `pyramid package` to a list.  Later, I will have that plot and others inserted from the list into a document.  But the `pyramid function` appears not to return a value.  How can I assign the pyramid plot to an object?

```
install.packages("pyramid") # functions to draw a population pyramid
library(pyramid)

# create a mock data frame to comparing this plot to a counterpart from plotrix

df <- data.frame(level1 = c(9,9,4,3,34,28), levelsame = c(9,9,4,3,34,28),
 title = c("Dir", "Exec. Dir", "Mgr", "Sr. Mgr", "Mgt Princ", "EVP+"))

        # assign the plot (hopefully) to an object
empty <- pyramid(df, Laxis = seq(1,35,5), AxisFM = "g", Csize = 0.8, Cgap = .5, Llab = "",
                                 Rlab = "", Clab = "Title", GL = F, Lcol = "blue", Rcol = "blue",
                                 Ldens = -1, main = "Distribution of Levels")

> empty
NULL
```

Likewise, if I assign the pyramid call to my list, nothing happens.  There is no value for the list returned by `pyramid`.

```
plotlist2[["pyramid"]] <-  pyramid(df, Laxis = seq(1,35,5), AxisFM = "g", Csize = 0.8, Cgap = .5, Llab = "",
                                  Rlab = "", Clab = "Title", GL = F, Lcol = "blue", Rcol = "blue",
                                  Ldens = -1, main = "Distribution of Levels")
> plotlist2[1]
[[1]]
NULL
```

I fear I am blundering in some obvious mis-understanding, so I welcome being set aright.  Thank you.

Comment: maybe you can try adding some code into the `pyramid`function with `trace`function or `fix(pyramid)` ?

Comment: Two new functions for me, so thank you.  I tried fix() but what is the syntax for trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `recordPlot()` function to save the current plot to a variable.

In your case you could do:

```
#print the plot
pyramid(df, Laxis = seq(1,35,5), AxisFM = "g", Csize = 0.8, Cgap = .5, Llab = "",
        Rlab = "", Clab = "Title", GL = F, Lcol = "blue", Rcol = "blue",
        Ldens = -1, main = "Distribution of Levels")

#save the current printed plot
pyrPlot<-recordPlot()

#plot it again
pyrPlot
```

You might have to enable the displaylist using `dev.control(displaylist ="enable")` for this to work depending on the graphical device you are using

Comment: Excellent! I did not know about recordPlot().  BTW, is there something equivalent like recordTable() or recordVariable() for other situations where a function does not return a value?

Comment: you can look at `capture.output(...)` if the function prints something in the console